# Saving favorite videos permanently

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, preferences

What i want :

- have the posibilite to choose from a tableView a video and add it to a favorite array . I wish to have this videos even if a close the app.

What i have tried:

```
- (IBAction)fav:(id)sender {

    if (f==0) {
        [favoriteArray addObject:[[stories copy] objectAtIndex:indexArray]];
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_selected.png"];
        //[self.favorite setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        NSMutableArray *url = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"url"]];
        NSMutableArray *title = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"title"]];
        NSMutableArray *picture = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"picture"]];

        [url addObjectsFromArray:[[stories copy] objectAtIndex:indexArray]];
        //        [title addObjectsFromArray:data];
        //        [picture addObjectsFromArray:data];



        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:url forKey:@"url"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:picture forKey:@"picture"];


        //f=1;
    }
```

but stories is an mutable array with objects,each object is a NSDictionary with 3 keys, and in url , i have all objects from stories after this method.

Comment: You title states NSBundle, but you question does, so what is it you want to do.

Comment: i want to save permanently my favorites video , even if i close app

Comment: De code you posted is correct for saving one item.

Comment: You could just save the whole array in the `NSUserDefaults `. But when you retrieve it from the `NSUserDefaults ` is immutable, thus you will have to make `mutableCopy` of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

to write your changes to disk.

You also seem to be overwriting the same value each time. Consider storing an array of objects rather than each type. E.g.

```
NSArray *temp = @[ 
                  @{@"url":@"", @"title":@"", @"picture":@""},
                  @{@"url":@"", @"title":@"", @"picture":@""}
                 ];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:temp forKey:@"favVideos"];
```